# Using between and Or together in Where clause SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two sets of dates I need to pull data for, these are TY and the equivalent dates for LY (8 weeks apart) . How is it possible to do this in the where clause?

```
orderdate between (cast(getdate()-420 as date) and cast(getdate()-364 as date)) or (cast(getdate()-56 as date) and cast(getdate()-1 as date))
```

Have tried many variations but get incorrect syntax errors.

Comment: Please provide sampled data and desired results.

Comment: *"Have tried many variations but get incorrect syntax errors."* and what were those attempts? What were the errors you got?

Comment: You should put `orderdate between` after the `or` as well...

Comment: @Tyron78 this worked perfectly. Thank you so much. And thank you to others for taking the time to respond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed syntax:

```
where (orderdate between cast(getdate()-420 as date) and cast(getdate()-364 as date))
       OR
      (orderdate between cast(getdate()-56 as date) and cast(getdate()-1 as date))
```

Answer (score 1):

`OR` condition can not be combined with `between`. You must have `cond1 OR cond2` as follows:

```
orderdate between (cast(getdate()-420 as date) and cast(getdate()-364 as date)) 
or orderdate between (cast(getdate()-56 as date) and cast(getdate()-1 as date))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my comment as answer: you should fix the syntax as follows:

```
orderdate between (cast(getdate()-420 as date) and cast(getdate()-364 as date))
or orderdate between (cast(getdate()-56 as date) and cast(getdate()-1 as date))
```